# Shall I apply for new a resident card after passport renewal?

Tags: immigration, indian-citizens, residence-cards, poland

I am an Indian citizen working in Warsaw, Poland. I have a temporary resident card, *Karta Pobytu,* which is valid until December 2020.

Last month, I renewed my passport at the Indian Embassy in Warsaw. As my current temporary resident card was issued on the previous passport, should I apply for a new resident card, or will my current card be valid? Will I have any problem in immigration if I travel with all passports (old and new) and the current resident card?

A few points related to this case:

- The resident card was issued until December 2020 even though my old passport was valid until October 2020.
- My new passport has all the details of my old passport on the back page.
- There is no mention of passport number on my temporary resident card.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Passport number is **not** contained on the **Karta Pobytu**, that would not be a reason to have the card replaced.

It would, however, be wise to inform the responsible authority of the new passport.

I am not sure if the should be done at the District Office (Urząd Gminy, Urząd Dzielnicy), to update your registration (Zameldowanie), or the Voivodeship (Immigration) Office

- possibly both

---

> **Replacement or loss of residence card**
>   A residence card must be replaced if:
>
> - data contained in the card have changed;
>
> ...

---

**Sources**:

- [Residence card - Migrant EN](http://www.migrant.info.pl/residence-card.html)
- [**When you go to immigration office in Poland**](https://www.facebook.com/chido.fajny/videos/1885446134859076)

Comment: Hi, I read the condition that "data contained in the card have changed". However, as passport number was not included in card, I was unsure if I need replacement of the card. I will check with the immigration office. As I was traveling to India soon, I was wondering if immigration will have any problem. Thank you.